# Retrieve data using joins with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query which retrieves data from a table which doesn't have data on another table.

I have table A with values

```
ID  StudentID    CLASSID
1      1            2
2      2            3
3      3            4
4      4            5
```

TABLE B with values

```
ID StudentID CLASSID
1   1           2
2   2           3
```

I am trying to return values from table A with ID 3,4 which is not available in TABLE B.

Query I have tried is

`SELECT *
FROM A AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM B AS b
    WHERE a.student_id = b.student_id
          AND a.CLASSID = b.CLASSID
);`

NOTE: As my problem was slow query. I have fixed this problem by creating index which made this query run fast.

Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Maybe a Homework Stack Exchange Community wouldn't be a bad idea...

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: `SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE StudentID NOT IN (SELECT STudentID FROM B)`

Comment: Sit down for half an hour with any decent book or online tutorial on the basics of SQL.

Comment: @Strawberry Sure sir. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
WHERE TableB.ID IS null
```

**Using NOT IN**

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE TableA.ID NOT IN ( SELECT ID FROM TableB)
```

**Using NO EXISTS**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tableB b
    WHERE a.studentsID = b.studentsID
    AND a.CLASSID = b.CLASSID
);
```

Comment: In this asked question, neither Tabel A or Table B does have a column named `name`. Also, always join on primary keys. `varchar` is not the best type for such thing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that @Cataklysim, My bad I didn't double check the Query before paste it here.